# Counting in the view issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm working with Ruby on Rails, and wrote an application to count results in my view, but it is not working.

Here are my tables:

```
|policies|
 |id| |num|
  1    1234
  2    5678
  3    1551    

|debts|
 |id| |policy_id|
  1        1
  2        1
  3        2
  4        2
  5        3
  6        2
```

I want this:

```
 |policy_id|   |count_num|
    1               2
    2               3
    3               1
```

Here is my controller:

```
class PolicyManagement < ApplicationController
  def generate_print_cupons
     @search = Debt.find(:all,:group=>:policy_id)
  end
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :policy
end

class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :debts
end
```

This is my view:

```
  <% @search.each do |debt| %>
     <%= debt.policy.num %>       
  <% end %>
```

I'm trying to count `debt.policy.num`.

I tried:

```
  <% @search.each do |debt| %>
     <%= debt.count(:num) %>       
  <% end %>
  undefined method `count' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation:0x7fb5afefd050>
```

And also I tried:

```
  <% @search.each do |debt| %>
     <%= debt.num.count %>       
  <% end %>

  undefined method `count' for 41:Fixnum
```

Please somebody can help me with this?

Comment: What exactly is `num` on the `policies` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to count the number of `debts` for each `policy`, why not perform the count from `Policy` rather than `Debt`?

Your controller would change to something like:

```
class PolicyManagement < ApplicationController
  def generate_print_cupons
     @search = Policy.all
  end
end
```

Then your view could be as trivial as:

```
<% @search.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy.debts.size %>       
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is `num` in `policies`?

Comment: I added more details on the top.Num is integer.

Comment: Updated the answer based on the question change

Comment: Many thanks!! it worked for me.
I appreciate your help. 1 point :)